# How can I use List in SwiftUI?

Tags: list, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct upper { 
    @State var data = \["aaa","bbb","ccc"\] 
} 

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View { 
        List(upper, id: .self) { item in 
            Text(item) 
        } 
    } 
} 

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider { 
    static var previews: some View { 
        ContentView() 
    } 
}
```

I am the beginner .I don't know how to solve the bug

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/). This is a simple issue, but it shows you have no foundation in the language yet. Your time will be better spent going through Apple's Tutorial above, as well As Stanford's iOS programming class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could use a list:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var data = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<data.count) { index in
                Text(data[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I would really recommend you to learn the basics of SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui